# WAMP server not working?

Tags: mysql, wamp

Okay, well my WAMP server isn't working now. Something happened to it and I haven't done anything. First the services wouldn't start. The apache was disable and I had to enable that one. So that works now.

But my MYSQL isn't working at all. I am searching for my Service name, but I can't find it. I think it been uninstalled by some means. Any help with my MYSQL service? Here's my logs and my ini.

my.ini:

```
# Example MySQL config file for medium systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (32M - 64M) where MySQL plays
# an important part, or systems up to 128M where MySQL is used together with
# other programs (such as a web server)
#
# You can copy this file to
# /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is C:\mysql\data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
basedir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24
log-error=c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log
datadir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24/data

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
#skip-networking

# Disable Federated by default
skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
log-bin=mysql-bin

# binary logging format - mixed recommended
binlog_format=mixed

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir     = /tmp/     
#log-update     = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#innodb_data_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
#innodb_log_arch_dir = C:\mysql\data/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 5M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld]
port=3306
```

MQL Log:

```
130517  0:03:50 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130517  0:03:50 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130517  0:03:50 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130517  0:03:50 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130517  0:03:50 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130517  0:03:50 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The first specified data file .\ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
130517  0:03:50  InnoDB: Setting file .\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
130517  0:03:51  InnoDB: Log file .\ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
130517  0:03:52  InnoDB: Log file .\ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
InnoDB: 127 rollback segment(s) active.
InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables
InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
130517  0:03:53  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130517  0:03:54 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 0
130517  0:03:54 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
130517  0:03:54 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
130517  0:03:54 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130517  0:03:54 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130517  0:03:54 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130517  0:03:54 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
130517  0:06:20 [Note] wampmysqld: Normal shutdown

130517  0:06:20 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130517  0:06:21  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130517  0:06:23  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
130517  0:06:23 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

130517  0:36:00 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130517  0:36:00 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130517  0:36:00 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130517  0:36:00 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130517  0:36:00 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130517  0:36:00 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130517  0:36:01 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130517  0:36:01  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130517  0:36:02 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
130517  0:36:02 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
130517  0:36:02 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
130517  0:36:02 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130517  0:36:02 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130517  0:36:04 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130517  0:36:04 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
130517  0:54:33 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130517  0:54:33 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130517  0:54:33 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130517  0:54:33 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130517  0:54:33 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130517  0:54:33 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130517  0:54:33 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130517  0:54:33  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130517  0:54:34 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
130517  0:54:34 [Note] Recovering after a crash using mysql-bin
130517  0:54:34 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
130517  0:54:34 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
130517  0:54:35 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
130517  0:54:35 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
130517  0:54:35 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130517  0:54:35 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130517  0:54:35 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130517  0:54:35 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
130517  0:56:28 [Note] wampmysqld: Normal shutdown

130517  0:56:28 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130517  0:56:28  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130517  0:56:28  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
130517  0:56:28 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

130517  0:57:26 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130517  0:57:26 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130517  0:57:26 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130517  0:57:26 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130517  0:57:26 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130517  0:57:26 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130517  0:57:26 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130517  0:57:26  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130517  0:57:27 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
130517  0:57:27 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
130517  0:57:27 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
130517  0:57:27 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130517  0:57:27 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130517  0:57:27 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130517  0:57:27 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
130517  1:01:42 [Note] wampmysqld: Normal shutdown

130517  1:01:42 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130517  1:01:42  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130517  1:01:43  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
130517  1:01:43 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

130517  1:01:43 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130517  1:01:43 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130517  1:01:43 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130517  1:01:43 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130517  1:01:43 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130517  1:01:43 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130517  1:01:43 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130517  1:01:43  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130517  1:01:44 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
130517  1:01:44 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
130517  1:01:44 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
130517  1:01:44 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130517  1:01:44 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130517  1:01:44 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130517  1:01:44 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
130517  1:03:47 [Note] wampmysqld: Normal shutdown

130517  1:03:47 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130517  1:03:47  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130517  1:03:47  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
130517  1:03:47 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

130517  1:03:51 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130517  1:03:51 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130517  1:03:51 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130517  1:03:51 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130517  1:03:51 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130517  1:03:51 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130517  1:03:51 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130517  1:03:51  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130517  1:03:52 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
130517  1:03:52 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
130517  1:03:52 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
130517  1:03:52 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130517  1:03:52 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130517  1:03:52 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130517  1:03:52 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
130517  1:10:10 [Note] wampmysqld: Normal shutdown

130517  1:10:10 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130517  1:10:10  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130517  1:10:10  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
130517  1:10:10 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

130517  1:10:14 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130517  1:10:14 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130517  1:10:14 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130517  1:10:14 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130517  1:10:14 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130517  1:10:14 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130517  1:10:14 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130517  1:10:14  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130517  1:10:15 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
130517  1:10:15 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
130517  1:10:15 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
130517  1:10:15 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130517  1:10:15 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130517  1:10:15 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130517  1:10:15 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
130517  1:10:24 [Note] wampmysqld: Normal shutdown

130517  1:10:24 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130517  1:10:24  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130517  1:10:25  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
130517  1:10:25 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete

130517  1:10:27 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130517  1:10:27 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130517  1:10:27 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130517  1:10:27 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130517  1:10:27 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130517  1:10:27 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130517  1:10:27 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130517  1:10:27  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130517  1:10:28 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
130517  1:10:28 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
130517  1:10:28 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
130517  1:10:28 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130517  1:10:28 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130517  1:10:28 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130517  1:10:28 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
130517  1:11:49 [Note] wampmysqld: Normal shutdown
```

Comment: Can you narrow down the problem a little (instead of posting 280 lines of stuff). It is a useful skill and it is called debugging. Start with trying to figure out if the database is working.

Comment: I can't even access the database. I don't even think I have the service anymore on my computer. I couldn't find any services that related to MYSQL.

Comment: Tried restarting it. Try the command line tool to connect. There could be a multitude of sins that are preventing it from working. As I am not sat at your computer (nor paid) it is difficult to tell. You just need a process of elimination. i.e. try root/password on the machine - if that works. Use workbench to check permissions for the user in particular. If not then look at error logs.

Comment: In windows 7,8 You can use "Event viewer" which help you to recognize what happen to your computer when Mysql & apache is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service should be named "wampmysqld" can you see that in your services? Is it running/started?

What were the last changes you made to the WAMP server? Some change must have upset it. When was it last working or what were you doing around the time it stopped working, anything like a reboot or changing the configs?

How do you know it's not working? As in how are you testing / connecting to it?

Worst case you could reinstall, it only takes a few minutes and the configurations can be copied from your previous install, however be wary of copying these as it sounds like you may have something wrong with them and you may also be installing a more recent version.

Comment: Thanks... I couldn't find it and it was disabled and when I googled trying to find the service name that never appeared.